# How to show just one Drive in Unity bar

Tags: unity, drive

I have two partitions and both are appearing in nautilus. On one partition windows is stored and other is for general use D:\drive.

In unity we have option to display mounted drives but I want ONLY ONE DRIVE TO APPEAR that is D:\ drive . Can this be done ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be done.

Unity by defualt show the mounted paritions and disks that are mounted on `/media` so to change that You have to mount the partition that you dont want to appear in place other than `/media`.

You can use `/mnt` for example

```
umount /media/Drive-C
mount -t type(ext4 or whatever) /dev/sd* /mnt
```

To automount this partition edit your `/etc/fstab` and change the old path **(/media)** of this partition to the new path **(/mnt)**